# SQL Server permissions to create/modify/drop *only* your database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security

How do I set permissions in SQL Server 2008 R2 such that the user can freely create, modify, and drop databases, but *only* their own - and can't read, see or modify anything else?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done I guess by creating new user and not mapping any DBs created by other users.Hence this user can have permission to do anything with DBs created by him or her.